# Is it a good workflow to do separate raw processing on different parts of an image?

Tags: post-processing, workflow, adobe-camera-raw

I have one photo.

I processed two slightly different pictures via Camera Raw from this one.

- One with Camera Raw settings focused on front object.
- One with Camera Raw Setting focused on background.
- And than combined these two pictures with masking.

Is this a good workflow?

Or would you recommend one Camera Raw use and than just masking and postproduction with other Photoshop tools?

Does Camera Raw have better quality in image data processing than other Photoshop tools?

Is it worth it to use one Camera Raw dialog per image or two when you are focusing on two things?

Comment: Hi stanley, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: You might search Photo.stackexchange for the topic 'focus stacking', as this has been answered before:
http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/667/what-are-the-best-practices-for-dof-stacking/1252#1252

http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/25731/why-would-a-photographer-do-focus-stacking

Comment: @cmason The OP means "concentrated on" when he says "focused", they are talking about an HDR not focus stacking workflow.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the approach you have described (take a single RAW file, process it once to accentuate one part of the image, export, then process it against to accentuate another part of the image, export, bring the two versions back together and selectively blend together to produce a third image) will work, I have done this on occasion where I could not obtain the desired result from a single RAW conversion.